# Webkit not rendering transformation transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

So a friend and I are having a bit of trouble with webkit. We're trying to animate a specific div to do a 720° rotation and using transition to animate the container itself, with the rotation being triggered by a javascript function.

This works absolutely fine in Firefox and IE, but once we switch over to a webkit-based browser, the rotation transition doesn't work.

When monitoring the page through the developer tools, we can see that the specific properties are assigned to the div, only the transition isn't being rendered.

The javascript is as such:

```
function projtheme() {  
var proj_title = document.getElementById("ring_1");
    proj_title.style.animation = "none";
    proj_title.style.WebkitAnimation = "none";
    proj_title.style.transform = "rotate(720deg)";
        proj_title.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(720deg)";
        proj_title.style.opacity = "0.1";
}

function projtheme_exit() {

    var proj_title = document.getElementById("ring_1");
    proj_title.style.animation = "spin_cw 60s linear infinite";
    proj_title.style.WebkitAnimation = "spin_cw 60s linear infinite";
    proj_title.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    proj_title.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(0deg)";
    proj_title.style.opacity = "0.6";
}
```

And said javascript functions are called in this way:

```
<span id="projbtn" onmouseout="projtheme_exit();" onmouseover="projtheme();"></span>
```

The CSS of the animated div has the properties it needs set to it (namely the transition properties):

```
#ring_1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    margin-top: -160px;
    margin-left: -150px;

    opacity: 0.6;

    display:block;

    animation: spin_cw 60s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: spin_cw 60s linear infinite;

    transition: all 0.5s ease;

}
```

Help on this would be much appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE:** Removing the animation function on said div seems to fix the issue, and the transition runs. The problem is, that animation needs to stay.

**UPDATE 2:** Inserting an alert between the lines that set the animation styles and those that set the transform properties inside of the script seems to make the transition work.